# Как обновить точки на существующей Yandex карте или удалить саму карту

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Есть страница на которой отображаются несколько точек, затем идут расчеты и добавляются новые координаты  к существующим. Как добавить новые координаты к существующей карте? Везде где нахожу примеры идет код типа `var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map",...` ,но мне не нужно создавать новую карту и  я никак не могу понять как взять объект существующей карты.

**Update**
Карта создается в другом js файле, поэтому напрямую к searchMap обратиться не удается

```
if (typeof ymaps !== "undefined" && ymaps !== null) {
  ymaps.ready(function() {
    var addedAddressesCount, address, addressPointsCollection, addresses, geoObject, i, len, results, searchMap;
    addresses = $('#service-map').data('addresses');
    searchMap = new ymaps.Map('service-map', {
      center: [addresses[0].latitude, addresses[0].longitude],
      zoom: 10,
      behaviors: ['drag', 'scrollZoom'],
      controls: []
    });
    addressPointsCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();
    addedAddressesCount = 0;
    results = [];
    for (i = 0, len = addresses.length; i < len; i++) {
      address = addresses[i];
      geoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
        geometry: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [address.latitude, address.longitude]
        },
        properties: {
          iconContent: $('.subscribe-btn').data('service-name'),
          hintContent: address.location
        }
      }, {
        preset: 'islands#blackStretchyIcon'
      });
      addressPointsCollection.add(geoObject);
      addedAddressesCount += 1;
      searchMap.geoObjects.add(addressPointsCollection);
      searchMap.setBounds(addressPointsCollection.getBounds());
      if (!(addedAddressesCount > 1)) {
        searchMap.setZoom(12);
      }
      results.push($('.map-btn').click(function() {
        var self;
        self = this;
        return $('body').scrollTo('.map', 'slow');
      }));
    }
    return results;
  });
}:

    if (typeof ymaps !== "undefined" && ymaps !== null) {
    ymaps.ready(function() {
    var addedAddressesCount, address, addressPointsCollection, addresses, geoObject, i, len, results, searchMap;
    addresses = $('#service-map').data('addresses');
    searchMap = new ymaps.Map('service-map', {
      center: [addresses[0].latitude, addresses[0].longitude],
      zoom: 10,
      behaviors: ['drag', 'scrollZoom'],
      controls: []
    });
    addressPointsCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();
    addedAddressesCount = 0;
    results = [];
    for (i = 0, len = addresses.length; i < len; i++) {
      address = addresses[i];
      geoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
        geometry: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [address.latitude, address.longitude]
        },
        properties: {
          iconContent: $('.subscribe-btn').data('service-name'),
          hintContent: address.location
        }
      }, {
        preset: 'islands#blackStretchyIcon'
      });
      addressPointsCollection.add(geoObject);
      addedAddressesCount += 1;
      searchMap.geoObjects.add(addressPointsCollection);
      searchMap.setBounds(addressPointsCollection.getBounds());
      if (!(addedAddressesCount > 1)) {
        searchMap.setZoom(12);
      }
      results.push($('.map-btn').click(function() {
        var self;
        self = this;
        return $('body').scrollTo('.map', 'slow');
      }));
    }
    return results;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Покажите код существующей карты

Comment: @tutankhamun, обновил

Answer (score 1):

Для себя решил таким образом:
searchMap сделал глобальным объектом,
в том месте, где нужно добавить новые точки удаляю старую карту

```
searchMap.destroy();
```

и дальше тем же кодом создаю карту заново, но уже с новыми точками